# Minimum size of each page table entry

Tags: operating-system

I am learning about operating systems and I am confused by this question.

Consider a 32-bit addressing scheme with 18 bits for the page number, 14 for the offset and 4GB of physical memory.

a.) How many Entries are there in the page table?

```
 This should just be 2^18 as there are 18 bits for the page number.
```

b.) What is the minimum size of each page table entry?

```
 I have no clue how to calculate this with the given information or what it means by min.
```

c.) What is the size of each page

```
This should just be 2^14 as the offset has 14 bits.
```

What does it mean by the min size and how do you calculate it with the given information?

Answer (score 1):

I HIGHLY suggest getting a different book.

> a.) How many Entries are there in the page table?

It could be anything. The address space sizes do not dictate the number of entries in a page table. Any book suggesting otherwise is written by idiots.

> b.) What is the minimum size of each page table entry?

Again, this is a stupid question. The are probably suggesting that that, if 18 bits of the address references a page then you need a minimum of 18 bits in a page table entry. How in the world would one implement 18-bit page tables?—I have no idea. As a practicable matter, a page table needs to have overhead bits for protection and paging management.

Let's say you move it up to 24-bits, giving you are round number of bytes and a few extra bites for overhead. Then you'd have poor performance from accessing misaligned data.

The reality here is that a page table entry in a 32-bit system is going to be 32-bits and one in a 64-bit system is going to to be 32- or 64-bits (or possibly a multiple).

I'd also note that your example is a "32-bit system" but has 18-bits for referencing page frames and 14-bits for offsets. That's only 22-bits.

That said, hardware implementations of a 32-bit processor architecture might support less than a full 32-bit address space. However, an ARCHITECTURE that that supported only 22-bits of addressing, would be totally FUed.

Asking what the minimum size of the page table is just asking the reader to engage in mental masturbation. They are just trying to make the simple complicated.

> c.) What is the size of each page

You got that one. The only question of the bunch that makes any sense.

In short, a page table entry has:

1. Enough bits to reference a physical page frame (or to reference the next level in a multi-level page table).
2. Page protection bits
3. Bits for managing paging (e.g. valid bit, dirty bit).

It's fairly simple.

Answer (score 0):

An entry in the page table is supposed to contain enough information to allow successful address translation. So, given some virtual address, you need to be able to get a correct physical address after looking in the corresponding page table entry.

Since you have `4 GB` (`2^32 B`) of physical memory you need a `32 bit` wide address to be able to address each single byte.

You already know that `14 bit` of the virtual address are used - without any translation - as offset. Thus you only need `32 - 14 = 18` additional bits to be able to address each byte separately. These `18 bits` form what is often called the frame number. Virtual address translation then becomes a mapping from a page number (the `18 bit` of the virtual address) to a frame number.

Note that the amount of bits used for frame number and page number need not be the same, as this example might suggest. If your system only had `1 GB` of physical memory, then `30 bits` would be enough to address every single byte, leaving you with `16 bits` for the frame number.

I used and assumed *"Having X of physical memory"* to mean the same as *"being able to maximal address X of physical memory"* in all of the above. The bit widths discussed do not depend on the actual memory configuration (how much RAM is currently available to the CPU) but rather the designed maximum capacity.